# collapsible bootstrap not returning and colored black

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

i already have a collapsible navbar but i have just issues with three things:

- collapsible not returning back when clicked (if list is dropped down)
- unnecessary underline
- collapsible button is black

also added the navbar-toggle in navbar header so that they stay in the same row
any help would be appreciated thank you.

[image: collapse]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header logo">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="main" class="navbar-left"><img src="img/logo_png_solo.png"></a>
    </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" id="nav-design">
      <li><a href="main" class="mwc-font-med">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="faq" class="mwc-font-med">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href="cards/membership.php" class="mwc-font-med">Membership</a></li>
      <li><a href="cards/list-claimed.php" class="mwc-font-med">Cards</a></li>
      <li><a href="cards/settings-profile.php" class="mwc-font-med">Settings</a></li>
      <li><a href="cards" class="mwc-font-med">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="cards/register.php" class="mwc-font-med">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9txzarws/

Comment: You are not importing jQuery in your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.navbar-nav.navbar-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
}
.logo img {
  height: 50px;
  transition: 5s;
}
.icon-bar {
  background-color: black;
}
.navbar ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">


<div class="bg-color-white strong">
  <div class="container">
    <br>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header logo">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a href="main" class="navbar-left"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" id="nav-design">
            <li><a href="main" class="mwc-font-med">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="faq" class="mwc-font-med">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="cards/membership.php" class="mwc-font-med">Membership</a></li>
            <li><a href="cards/list-claimed.php" class="mwc-font-med">Cards</a></li>
            <li><a href="cards/settings-profile.php" class="mwc-font-med">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="cards" class="mwc-font-med">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="cards/register.php" class="mwc-font-med">Register</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following fiddle. Hope this will solve your mentioned issues

- collapsible not returning back when clicked (if list is dropped
  down)
- unnecessary underline
- collapsible button is black

[Try this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/strwj17f/1/)

```
<html >
  <head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
 <style>
  .navbar {
  background: white;
  border: white;
  }
  .navbar-nav.navbar-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
  }
  .icon-bar{
  background-color:#000
  }
  .logo img {
  height: 50px;
  transition: 5s;
  }
  .navbar-nav{
  text-align:center;
  }
  .navbar-nav a{
  color:#000;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:18px
  }
 </style>
 <body>
  <div class="bg-color-white strong">
  <div class="container">
  <br>
  <nav class="navbar">
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header logo">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
           <a href="main" class="navbar-left"><img src="img/logo_png_solo.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" id="nav-design">
              <li><a href="main" class="mwc-font-med">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="faq" class="mwc-font-med">FAQ</a></li>
              <li><a href="cards/membership.php" class="mwc-font-med">Membership</a></li>
              <li><a href="cards/list-claimed.php" class="mwc-font-med">Cards</a></li>
              <li><a href="cards/settings-profile.php" class="mwc-font-med">Settings</a></li>
              <li><a href="cards" class="mwc-font-med">Login</a></li>
              <li><a href="cards/register.php" class="mwc-font-med">Register</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
  </nav>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> . 
  </script>
  </html>
```